# circleci: manual approval step ignored

Tags: circleci

I have the following two workflows defined:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  deploy-msp-navigator-production:
    jobs:
      - build-job:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
            branches:
              ignore: /.*/
          context: msp-navigator
      - approve:
          type: approval
          requires:
            - build-job
      - deploy-job:
          requires:
            - approve
          context: msp-navigator
      - deploy-functions:
          requires:
            - approve
          context: msp-navigator
  deploy-msp-navigator-dev:
    jobs:
      - build-job:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
          context: msp-navigator-dev
      - deploy-job:
          requires:
            - build-job
          context: msp-navigator-dev
      - deploy-functions:
          requires:
            - build-job
          context: msp-navigator-dev
```

The `msp-navigator-dev` one (without the approval step) works fine:

[image: all jobs executed]

But the production one doesn't. It simply stops after the `build-job`:

[image: not all jobs processed]

I feel like I'm missing something really stupid here, but I just don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out to CircleCI support and got the following answer:

> The build was triggered by a "tag push". By default, CircleCI will build for all branches but for no tags.
>
> The build-job in the deploy-msp-navigator-production workflow is executed because a tag filter was specified and the tag you pushed matches the regular expression in the filter.
>
> However when the execution reaches the approve job, as no tag filter is specified the job is skipped.
>
> To modify this behaviour you'll need to add the tag filter to both approve (and subsequent) jobs

So it works with the following setup:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  deploy-msp-navigator-production:
    jobs:
      - build-job:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
            branches:
              ignore: /.*/
          context: msp-navigator
      - approve:
          type: approval
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
          requires:
            - build-job
      - deploy-job:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
          requires:
            - approve
          context: msp-navigator
      - deploy-functions:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
          requires:
            - approve
          context: msp-navigator
  deploy-msp-navigator-dev:
    jobs:
      - build-job:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
          context: msp-navigator-dev
      - deploy-job:
          requires:
            - build-job
          context: msp-navigator-dev
      - deploy-functions:
          requires:
            - build-job
          context: msp-navigator-dev
```